# branching 3 visual studio projects in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have an application that in visual studio is made of up three different projects.  The Winforms app needs all three to run.  In TFS the projects are located under 1 project name.  Underneath that project (in TFS) there are 3 folders with the names of the projects in Visual Studio with their corresponding code files.

### TFS Project

1. VS project
2. VS project
3. VS project

I am attempting to branch these projects so that the three of us developers are working in a separate development branch and keep this as the main release.  When I attempt to do a branch I get 3 separate folders of each project under the TFS project.  Most of our development work involves all there projects so I would like a branch of all three projects if possible.  I am a TFS and source control noob so it is very possible I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an additional level between TFS project and your projects, so you could use it as a container for your branches. Usually this is called Main or trunk:

```
TFS Project
- Main / trunk
- - VS project 1
- - VS project 2
- - VS project 3
```

Now you can branch the Main/trunk folder. You can name it as you want, but using devs names sounds strange, never saw that. Usually it is a feature or version branch:

```
TFS Project
- Main / trunk
- - VS project 1
- - VS project 2
- - VS project 3
- Branch 1 (Dev1, Release 1.2, Feature) -> branch of Main
- - VS project 1
- - VS project 2
- - VS project 3
- Branch 2 (Dev2, Release 1.3, Feature) -> branch of Main
- - VS project 1
- - VS project 2
- - VS project 3
```